# LinkedHashMap and TreeMap which is faster?

Tags: java, hash

I have some data that's going to be coming in sorted order (first the entire set of keys in sorted order and then duplicates in random order). So, I could use both a LinkedHashMap or a TreeMap to preserve the ordering (right?). My question then is, which of them is faster and which is more space efficient?

Comment: LinkedHashMap would be better i think. reason is your order insert order is the right order, on the other hand treemap(red black tree) cost o(lgn) to reblance

Comment: @Andrew Barber: But the question is so direct.. which of the two data structures should I use? I'll narrow it down to speed being the only criterion.. will that help?

Comment: It is documented that LinkedHashMap is O(1) for insertion and retrieval, where TeeMap is O(log(N)).

Comment: I've reopened the question. I might recommend describing a little bit more what the specific issue you have that brings up the question, as that might (even subtly) affect the answer. /cc @EJP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LinkedHashMap is faster for insertion because it won´t have to unnecessarily compare values while inserting like TreeMap, as stated by @EJP. And since LinkedHashMap only needs a link for the previous and to the next key, while TreeMap needs a link to the parent node and 1+ links to children, I think that TreeMap will also consume a slightly bigger memory.

So my vote is for LinkedHashMap. Less memory, less time, and of course, less CPU .